# codeigniter upload without redirecting to success page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

How can I upload an Image in codeigniter without redirecting to the success page using Ajax .
 Everytime I click the save it displays a 
 You did not select a file to upload.

Here's My View :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("input[name='upload']").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('Upload/do_upload')?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {
            swal("Success!", "Uploaded!", "success");
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
            {
     $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
     $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
            }
        }

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error adding / update data');
    }
});

});
 });
 </script>
  </head> 
  <body>

  <?php echo $error;?>

  <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload'); ?>
  <input type="file" name="userfile" id="uf" size="20" />
  <span class="help-block"></span>
  <br /><br />

  <input type="button" name="upload"  value="upload" />

  </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

And Here's my Controller :

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('pages/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/registeredlist/upload', array('error' => ' ' ));
            $this->load->view('pages/footer');
    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $data = array();
            $data['error_string'] = array();
            $data['inputerror'] = array();
            $data['status'] = TRUE;

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                    //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $data['inputerror'][] = 'userfile';
                    $data['error_string'][] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    $data['status'] = FALSE;
                }
            if($data['status'] === FALSE)
            {
                echo json_encode($data);
                exit();
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't upload an image with Ajax like that. File uploads are slightly different than an ordinary post. You need to use either "formdata" (search for ajax formdata) or to use a ready ajax upload library with fallbacks for browsers with out formdata-support in ajax calls.

Comment: ...and to stop the browser from redirecting and run your script instead, use  preventDefault(): `jQuery("input[name='upload']").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //...rest of your ajax script`. This will stop the browser from triggering it's "default" behavior, which is to actually post the forml

Comment: Tried to do the same with no success. Ended up using the default submit process.

Comment: I got this working by using AjaxFileUpload.js
https://github.com/davgothic/AjaxFileUpload